# How to allign text vertical and horizontal?

Tags: html, css

I have layout like this i want have text the centered horizontaly and verticaly

I tried to do with this (display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle)

But when i tried it i ruin my all layout:

```css
li {list-style:none;}
h3 {margin:0px}
p {margin:0px}
ul {margin:0px; padding:0px}
```

```html
<li style="background:#263F73; border-style: dotted; border-width: 1px; height:100px;">

  <div style="width:70%; float: left; "><h6 style="margin:0px;"><h3>Text</h3></h6></div>
  <ul style="float: right; height:100%; width: 30%;">
    <li>
      <li style=" height:50%; background:#ffffff;"><p style=" margin: 0px;"><div><p class="centerText">Text</p></div></li>
      <li style=" height:50%; background:#fff465;"><p style=" margin: 0px;"><div><p class="centerText">Text</p></div></li>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
</li>
```

Comment: `<h6 style="margin:0px;"><h3>Text</h3></h6>` this is SO bad!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to align text vertically center in div with css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

First of all ***have in mind that your HTML is not valid!*** (like `h3` can't be in `h6`, `li` must be inside `ul`, if using external css, don't use inline too...)

If your text is only single line ever, apply `line-height` same as container:

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}
p {
  margin: 0px
}
ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
.centerText {
  line-height: 50px;
}
.text1 {
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<li style="background:#263F73; border-style: dotted; border-width: 1px; height:100px;">

  <div style="width:70%; float: left; ">
    <h6 style="margin:0px;" class="text1">Text1</h6>
  </div>
  <ul style="float: right; height:100%; width: 30%;">
    <li style=" height:50%; background:#ffffff;">
      <p style=" margin: 0px;">
        <p class="centerText">Text2</p>

    </li>
    <li style=" height:50%; background:#fff465;">
      <p style=" margin: 0px;">
        <p class="centerText">Text3</p>
    </li>
  </ul>

</li>
```

If you have multiline text, than use `display: table` and `display: table-cell`

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}
p {
  margin: 0px
}
ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
.table {
  display: table;
}
.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<li style="background:#263F73; border-style: dotted; border-width: 1px; height:100px;">

  <div style="width:70%; float: left; height: 100%;" class="table">
    <div style="margin:0px;" class="tcell">Text1<br/>Multiple</div>
  </div>
  <ul style="float: right; height:100%; width: 30%;">
    <li style=" height:50%; background:#ffffff; width: 100%" class="table">
      <p style=" margin: 0px;" class="tcell">
        Text2
      </p>
    </li>
    <li style=" height:50%; background:#fff465; width: 100%" class="table">
      <p style=" margin: 0px;" class="tcell">
        Text3
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>

</li>
```